# Change variable value in CodeIgniter subview

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a main view in my CI app in which I declare a variable.
That main view loads several subview in a loop.

I would like these subviews to modify my variable so that at the end of the loop its value would be updated.

Example:

**main_view.php**

```
<?php
$my_var = false;
foreach($a_views as $s_view){
   $this->load->view($s_view, array('my_var' => $my_var);
}
var_dump($my_var); // Still false
?>
```

**sub_view.php**

```
<?php $my_var = true; ?>
```

Comment: Share with us your goal, there's must be another way of achieving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the code for the `$this->load->view` function.
The data you pass to the view is "one-way" which means it's available and can be modified only in the view itself.

Which means you'll have to find another way to achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Keep in mind that according to what I've understood from your question you're trying to have some "logical manipulation" using "views" which is kind of breaking the MVC architecture.

```
/**
 * View Loader
 *
 * Loads "view" files.
 *
 * @param   string  $view   View name
 * @param   array   $vars   An associative array of data
 *              to be extracted for use in the view
 * @param   bool    $return Whether to return the view output
 *              or leave it to the Output class
 * @return  object|string
 */
public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}
```

Comment: I agree about breaking the MVC architecture. That was essentially for my curiosity. I will try something cleaner. Thank you anyway

Comment: It might be tempting sometimes to break the MVC architecture but it won't worth it (from experience).